# SharePoint - Approaching Website Storage Limit Email

Tags: email

How can I go about changing the distribution list as well as the email text for the email that goes out to site collection admin when a site collection approaches it's size limit?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same. Has anybody found a way to change the text? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email goes to everyone who is a Site Collection Administrator, so the way to change who gets it is to change the membership of that role.  How would you like to change the text of the email?  It would seem that it's pretty clear.

M.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. That was the last place I needed to check for the dist list. We would still like to change the email text to something else. Is there a file in 12 hive where the text is defined?

Comment: I found out that email text is coming from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN\1033\FPEXT.MSG. I dont want to change the text there directly as its an OOB file. Is there a way to override the text without changing the actual file?

Comment: @Emon: This is a good question you should ask!!

Answer (score 2):

Login to SharePoint Central Administration with System account

Go to:

> Application Management --> Site collection --> Specify Quota Templates
>   --> edit existing template --> Change storage Limit to your wish (ex: 100mb to 300 mb) --> warning email Limit to your wish (ex: 80 mb to
>   280 mb) --> save.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Was there ever an answer to this?  I'm trying to do the same thing.  I don't want to edit the FPEXT.MSG file, but I don't see a way around it.

It looks like you can write a handler to catch and change Alert emails, just not the storage limit email.  This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is the only way to change the text

```
#Specify the URL to your SharePoint admin center site, e.g. https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com

$url = 'https://aftar.sharepoint.com/'

#Specify a folder path to output the results into
$path = '.\'

#SMTP details
$Smtp = '<SmtpServer>'
$From = '<SenderEmailAddress>'  
$To = '<RecipientEmailAddress>'
$Subject = 'Site Storage Warning'  
$Body = 'Storage Usage Details'

if($url -eq '') {
  $url = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the SharePoint admin center URL'
}

Connect-SPOService -Url $url

#Local variable to create and store output file  
$filename = (Get-Date -Format o | foreach {$_ -Replace ":", ""})+'.csv'  
$fullpath = $path+$filename

#Enumerating all sites and calculating storage usage  
$sites = Get-SPOSite
$results = @()

foreach ($site in $sites) {
  $siteStorage = New-Object PSObject
  
  $percent = $site.StorageUsageCurrent / $site.StorageQuota * 100  
  $percentage = [math]::Round($percent,2)

  $siteStorage | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Site Title" -Value $site.Title
  $siteStorage | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Site Url" -Value $site.Url
  $siteStorage | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Percentage Used" -Value $percentage
  $siteStorage | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Storage Used (MB)" -Value $site.StorageUsageCurrent
  $siteStorage | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Storage Quota (MB)" -Value $site.StorageQuota

  $results += $siteStorage
  $siteStorage = $null
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path $fullpath -NoTypeInformation

#Sending email with output file as attachment  
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $Smtp -To $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -Attachments $fullpath -Body $Body -Priority high
```

`$url` is the URL of your SharePoint admin center. If the $url variable is left empty, you will be prompted to enter the URL of your admin center site.

`$path` is the file system path you want the CSV file to output to.

`<SmtpServer>` is the name of your SharePoint Migration Tool mail server.

`<SenderEmailAddress>` is the global admin or SharePoint admin account that appears in the From line in the warning email.

`<RecipientEmailAddress>` is the admin account that will receive the email warning.